# WT588D-U use of DAC audio output

Tags: audio, dac

U
When I use the PMW output with a speaker  like this, all is good:
http://www.instructables.com/id/WT588D-Standalone-Arduino-sound-player/?ALLSTEPS

I want to test DAC output so I did it like this but the sound seems to be too high for my amp (2 basics amplified speakers), I ear only lots off distortion, did I miss something?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the voltage level is too high for your amplified speakers. You could try adding a basic volume control to it, using a potentiometer like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgfMxQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Ok thx indeed adding a resistor like this is working :)
http://snag.gy/2Ldrc.jpg

Some places tells that I have to add a capacitor between ground and resistor but did not find the good value, it is messing with the sound level.